# jquery tablesorter plugin - retain alternative row colors

Tags: jquery, row, tablesorter, backcolor

I took an html table that I am applying alternative row colors to, and I added jquery table sorter on it so users can sort the table.

The issue is that the alternative row colors are all messed up now as (based on the sorting) there are multiple rows with the same background color.

Is there any way to reset the alternative row color with jquery table sorter?

Comment: I find the easiest way is to just scan through the table when finished sorting and alternate the classname for the proper L&F.

Comment: i dont follow you here.  it seems like jquery is doing all the sorting so where do you get a "hook" to go in and reset your table

Comment: Can i suggest another table component instead of jquery tablesorter ?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There's already a default widget `zebra`, built into the core, which applies the classes `odd` and `even` to alternate rows. It works whether or not you have added `class=even/odd` to the html file.

It's really easy to set up. I simply followed the instructions on the [table sorter website](http://tablesorter.com/docs/), and then modified the document ready function to the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter({ 
    widgets: ['zebra'] 
    }); 
    } 
); 
</script>
```

I made an example while answering the question. You can [view the result in action](https://alasdairnicol.github.io/tablesorter-zebra-example/), or [see the example code](https://github.com/alasdairnicol/tablesorter-zebra-example).

Answer (score 6):

Based on Anthony's answer, but rephrased as a one-liner (mostly):

```
function fixStripes() {
    $('table tr').removeClass('odd even')
        .filter(':even').addClass('even').end()
        .filter(':odd').addClass('odd');
}

$("table").bind("sort", fixStripes);
```

JQuery calls can be "chained" as above, using operations like `filter()` to limit the selected elements, and `.end()` to "reset" to the last selection. Put another way, each `.end()` "undoes" the previous `.filter()`. The final `.end()` is left off, since there's nothing to do after that.

Comment: That should be `$('table tr')`

Comment: BTW, tablesorter now seems to call sortStart and sortEnd rather than just sort.

Answer (score 5):

In order to maintain the zebra stripes after a sort has taken place you need to trigger the zebra widget again.

```
$('#myTable')
.tablesorter({ widgets: ['zebra'] })
.bind('sortEnd', function(){
    $("#myTable").trigger("applyWidgets"); 
});
```

This is less of a hack, as you will be reusing the logic of the zebra widget rather than replicating it.

**Note:** This kind of work-around is only required in instances where the default zebra widget is failing. I have found in most circumstances that this hack is not required as the widget is operating correctly post sort.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
function fixStripes() {
     var i = 0;
     var rowclass;
     $("table tr").each(function() {
          $(this).removeClass("odd even");
          rowclass = (i%2 == 1) ? "odd" : "even";
          $(this).addClass(rowClass);
      });
}

$("table").bind("sort", fixStripes);
```

Oh, and if you want a really simple fix, you could hold your breath for this CSS pseudo-class to get picked up by all the major browsers:

```
table tr:nth-child(n+1) {
    color: #ccc;
}
```

But my guess is based on how FF and company handle CSS for dynamic HTML, it would set your stripes onload, but not apply the CSS after you sort. But I'd like to know for sure.

Comment: Think you also need `$(this).removeClass('odd even')` to make sure each row gets reset correctly.

Answer (score 1):

**Revised and Latest working solution - inbuilt**
**This will also enable the change of colour on click.**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#tblLookupResult').tablesorter({ widthFixed: true, sortList: [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2]], theme: 'blue', widgets: ['zebra'] })
                          .tablesorterPager({ container: $("#pager"), size: $(".pagesize option:selected").val() });

    $('#tbltable1 tbody tr').live('click', function () {               
                    if ($(this).hasClass('even')) {
                        $(this).removeClass('even');
                        $(this).addClass('ui-selected');
                    }

                    else if ($(this).hasClass('odd')) {
                        $(this).removeClass('odd');
                        $(this).addClass('ui-selected');
                    }
                    else {
                        $(this).removeClass('ui-selected');
                        $(".tablesorter").trigger("update");
                        $(".tablesorter").trigger("applyWidgets");                         
                    }

        });

    });
</script>
```

Now everything should kick itself out !

Answer (score 0):

Via your css:

```
  table.tablesorter tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #ECFAFF;
    }
```